# using click data to update a plot

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that will allow user to click in multiple places on  a plot, and then click a button to add these coordinates to the plot.  The catch is that I will need to pass these coordinates as a vector to an external C program, so I need to make this list (vector) available externally from within the shiny app.  This is what I am unable to do.

I have included a toy example below (which renders fine) and a rather sorry attempt to create such a list. What I would like with this toy example is to produce a list of x,y coordinates and then to take the x and y coordinates from this list and add them to the vectors taken from mtcars, producing an updated plot upon clicking an "accept new values" button, for example.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks, Matt

```
library(shiny)
listo <- numeric()

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  listo2 <-numeric() #create list
  obs <- observe({listo2 = append(listo2, input$plot_clickx)}) #adding clicks to list

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a list, that is suited for reactive programming:
So `?reactiveValues`is your friend:
The following code enables you to

- save the click points in a "reactive list"
- plot the (not yet modified) points by click of an actionButton

The Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),
  actionButton("updateplot", "Update Plot:")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  val <- reactiveValues(clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL)

  observe({
      input$plot_click
      isolate({
        val$clickx = c(val$clickx, input$plot_click$x)
        val$clicky = c(val$clicky, input$plot_click$y)     
      })
  }) #adding clicks to list

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
    input$updateplot
    isolate({
      points(val$clickx, val$clicky)
    })
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x = ", val$clickx, ", y = ",val$clicky, "\n")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```